# Adding special signs(slash, dot) to header of kendo-grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I use `ngFor` to create columns dynamically:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
  <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="{{column}}"></kendo-grid-column>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

It works perfectly. Example of dynamic creating of columns [can be seen here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/).

However, I need to add special signs(slash **"/"**, dot **"."**, space **" "**) to column name. For example:

**TypeScript:**

```
public columns: string[] = [
  "CompanyName", "ContactName", "Contact Title", "Depart./Time"
];

public gridData: any[] = sampleCustomers = [{
    "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
    "Contact Title": "Sales Representative",
    "Depart./Time": "London/11:35"
    }, {
    "Id": "ANATR",
    "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
    "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo",
    "Contact Title": "Owner",
    "Depart./Time": "Cape town/14:10"
    }, {
    "Id": "ANTON",
    "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
    "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno",
    "Contact Title": "Owner",
    "Depart./Time": "Tokyo/06:15"
}];
```

**HTML:**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column
            field="{{column}}"                
        >

        </kendo-grid-column>
      </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

And when I add *slash, dot*(e.g. "Depart./Time") signs, I see the following error:

> Unexpected token )

if I add *space* in column name(e.g. "Contact Title"), then I see the following error:

> ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Is it possible to add such signs (*space, slash, dot*) to header of column?

Comment: If you can change the field property from your data, you can get an alternative title using the `title` binding.

Comment: @PierreDuc could you explain, pls, or just make an answer. I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `DisplayName[]` property in your view model? Such as `[DisplayName("Depart./Time")]`.

Comment: @Supersnake no, could you show an example?

Comment: Take a look at this [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically you add `[DisplayName("Depart./Time")]` above the column name in your model. The value of `DisplayName` will be used as the column header.

Comment: @Supersnake there is no such feature as Attribute. It is not WPF or MVC, it is Angular 2 and Kendo Grid.